# My background stretch changes when i open application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, stretch

My background image changes when i open application

I used this:

```
<Grid Name ="alo">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Smth\Pics\135.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
        </Grid.Background>
```

[background before launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy39Z.png)

[background afterlaunch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJFwV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is shown in its native, unstretched size.

In order to make it fill the Grid while keeping its aspect ratio, set Stretch to UniformToFill:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Smth\Pics\135.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```